# How to id with foreign key in my table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my [**screenshot**](http://postimg.org/image/3o1abiuoz/)

I need a foreign key for id for table name `studentresult`.

I need to use `id` from table name student.

I'm new to .net and SQL Server, so can anyone guide me to resolve this?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: why post pictures, just show the code/schema

Comment: @Drew: what you mean.. is there no picture?

Comment: Bill, just update to Win 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field in `studentresult` table to point `student` table (i.e. idstudent), so add a foreign key constraint.

You can add a foreign key constraint using GUI (right click with mouse and choose Relations), or by script as follow:

```
ALTER TABLE studentresult 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student
FOREIGN KEY (idstudent)
REFERENCE student(id)
```

**EDIT**

After your new screenshot (in answer comment):

In the table structure [`studentresult`](http://s18.postimg.org/i912adw7d/untitled.jpg) you must add a newd field named:

id_student with data_type int, so you save the table structure

After you open Sql Server Management Studio (have you got it? If no, you can download an express edition it's free) and add the foreign key constraint with script posted above in this answer.

Comment: I can't able to understand, where i can place your code.? in right click of my table page only contains set primary key.. thanks

Comment: 1. You can open studentresult table structure and add idstudent field; 2. Add a foreign key constraint

Comment: yes.. i posted one image right.. in that you see id field..

Comment: @Rani: No, in that image you show student table, not studentresult table. id is primary key, but idstudent is foreign key to student table

Comment: No its by my mistaken.. its the table name called studentresult.. I try to add foreign key.. unfortunately its add primary key.. thank you

Comment: Dear, you must add a primary key on id field, so you must add aforeign key on new field id_student

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95678/discussion-between-rani-and-joe-taras).

Comment: 1. http://s18.postimg.org/i912adw7d/untitled.jpg 2. http://s2.postimg.org/hq7m42hkp/untitled1.jpg ...here is studentresult and student respectively...

Comment: I am using sql server now itself... I have added id_student in the table studentresult.. i can't understand where i can add script?

Comment: When you open a table structure, you have open a page. If you click on the button "new query" you open another page where you can run scripts (like mine)

Comment: OK..but it shows error.. The ALTER TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

To create a FOREIGN KEY constraint on the "Id" column of "studentresult" table when the "student" table is already created, use the following SQL:

```html
ALTER TABLE student
ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES studentresult(id)
```